# How log rotation is done in Tomcat for access logs

Tags: logging, tomcat, logs

How log rotation is done in Tomcat ie catalina.out and access.out ?

We can logrotate for catalina.out :

```
# vim /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat7
/var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out {
  copytruncate
  daily
# rotate 52
  rotate 90
  compress
  missingok
  create 640 tomcat7 adm
}
```

In same way can we do it for access logs ?

Comment: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`logrotate`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) is a tool independent from tomcat. It can be used with log files generated by any kind of applications.

You can add a rule for the `access.out` tomcat log file in the `/etc/logrotate.d/tomcat7` logrotate configuration file. If you want to apply the same rules as for `/var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out` you can modify your configuration file like this:

```
/var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out /var/log/tomcat7/access.out{
  copytruncate
  daily
# rotate 52
  rotate 90
  compress
  missingok
  create 640 tomcat7 adm
}
```

Read the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) for more information.